# Strict Mode in JavaScript works with their frameworks?

Tags: javascript

I am studying JavaScript and came across the Strict Mode ("use strict"). I wonder if it works with JavaScript frameworks(like jQuery, Angular.js, etc) if I put this command in a `.js` file, or if only work with pure JavaScript? And It is currently feasible to use it? because it is only supported by the latest versions of some browsers.

Comment: You can put it in any file where you are the author of that file... if not you won't be able to predict how the code will function

Comment: If you are the author of a function or a file then you can mark that as in `strict` mode

Comment: What makes you think that strict mode only works in “pure” JavaScript? There’s no fundamental difference between framework code in JavaScript and general code in JavaScript.

Comment: Perhaps why so seen examples that did not use frameworks there are doubts arose me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is a execution mode of javascript, it has nothing to do with libraries like jQuery or angularjs.

So yes you can use strict mode in your code even though you are using some javascript libraries. But when you use strict mode make sure that the mode is applied only those code which you have authored, because we won't know whether another persons code is compatible with this mode.

Answer (score 2):

`strict mode` is subset of javascript and it written as a string `"use strict"` so if older browser doesn't support the `strict mode` then it consider as a simple string and just ignore it and you code work as simple javascript so it is feasible to use. I could not find strict mode in jQuery source code but I'm not sure about that.